# Springboot mongo docker-compose fail to connect

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

My docker-compose.yml is as shown

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend-service:
    image: 'storio-360-service:v1.0'
    build: .
    container_name: storio-360-service
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
    depends_on:
      - db_mongo
    links:
      - db_mongo
  db_mongo:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: db_mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - /home/bob/Bob/data:/data/db
    restart: always
```

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM openjdk:8u111-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD /target/backend-service-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
CMD curl "db_mongo:27018"
```

Because of this set up, my repository in my spring has this code

```
@Repository
public class WatcherRepository {

    private MongoOperations mongoOps;

    @Autowired
    public WatcherRepository() {
        String myHost = "db_mongo";
        this.mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(myHost), MongoConstant.DATABASE_NAME));
    }

    // Other code to access the mongo db
}
```

However, when i run docker-compose up --build,

I get the following when Spring boot is starting up,

```
02:24:55.871 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
storio-360-service    | 02:24:55.923 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5d3faa779470450001317225', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
storio-360-service    | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
storio-360-service    |         at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62)
storio-360-service    |         at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
storio-360-service    |         at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114)
storio-360-service    |         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
storio-360-service    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
storio-360-service    |         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
storio-360-service    |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
storio-360-service    |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
storio-360-service    |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
storio-360-service    |         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
storio-360-service    |         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
storio-360-service    |         at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59)
storio-360-service    |         at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57)
storio-360-service    |         ... 3 common frames omitted
storio-360-service    | 02:24:56.060 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500
```

Then Spring boot will shown that it is waiting for calls as it sets up successfully.

```
02:34:39.274 [main] INFO  o.d.i.i.storio.service.Service - Started Service in 5.353 seconds (JVM running for 6.085)
```

However, when i make the api call which will call the mongodb, it shows me the error

```
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

I am new to Docker and it is clear that my springboot cannot access mongo. What am i doing wrong in my Dockerfile or docker-compose? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are forwarding your mongodb port to `27018`

```
   - 27018:27017
```

and you haven't specified `27018` in Spring config.

Hence Spring boot by default tries to connect to `27017`

Solution:
Either remove the port forwarding, or update Spring Boot config to use mongo at `27018`

---

Update:

Here are some Spring Boot's mongo auto configuration tips for the OP.

Have dependency on a mongodb starter for spring boot

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Provide Mongo DB details in application properties.

```
spring.data.mongodb.database= # Database name.
spring.data.mongodb.host= # Mongo server host. Cannot be set with URI.
spring.data.mongodb.password= # Login password of the mongo server. Cannot be set with URI.
spring.data.mongodb.port= # Mongo server port. Cannot be set with URI.
spring.data.mongodb.username= # Login user of the mongo server. Cannot be set with URI
```

(Here the OP needs to specify his mongodb host and port)

Now, the only thing left is to autowire `MongoTemplate`, where ever you want to use.

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Comment: Hi I try tried to change in the Repository class. String myHost = "db_mongo:27018";
        this.mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(myHost), MongoConstant.SG_FEEDS)); However, it is still not working. How can i correctly change the port from 27017 to 27018

Comment: In your application.properties add `spring.data.mongodb.port= 27018`

Comment: Looks like you have conflicts with Spring Boot. Using spring boot you don't need to create `MongoTemplate` on your own, SB does it for you based on the DB details provided in properties file

Comment: The mongotemplate allows me to query mongo in a native way. It works on development. Is the way i can specify the port difference in the code or docker compose?

Comment: @Desmond To my answer, i have tried to add brief of how Spring Boot can auto-create MongoTemplate. Hope it helps

Comment: Did anyone solve this problem? I am having the same issue. My mongo db on docker is running on 27017, however springbot fails to connect: localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017